# Send custom headers from calling an API gateway from lambda causing 403 Forbidden

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Hi I have a couple of API gateways with different functionality, both endpoints without any authorizer and the endpoints call a lambda that has some logic, so I want to call from the lambda in the first API to an endpoint from the second API, the problem is that I am getting a forbidden error, not sure why; the endpoints are available and working properly form postman but not form the lambda
I check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080394/calling-aws-api-gateway-from-aws-lambda) for reference but with no luck

The code from the first lamdbda is something like this:

```
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    method='POST'
    headers=event['headers']
    headers['custom-header1']
    headers['custom-header2']
    body='some test body'
    url = 'https://dummy.execute-api.dummyregion.amazonaws.com/dummy/test'
    response = requests.request(method, url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

EDIT add error

```
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://dummy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/transformer/transformer: HTTPErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 28, in lambda_handler    print('raise_for_status',response.raise_for_status())  
File "/var/runtime/botocore/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status    
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 
403 Client Error: Forbidden for URL: 
https://dummy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/transformer/transformer/
```

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: I add the text from response.raise for status()

Comment: a screen shot of the non-working api configuration might help, i am not sure what `/transformer/transformer/` is ?

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I was able to send the request, I suppose the message was "kind" of right because I was getting a 403 "forbidden", but not that specific, the error was that I was sending the same headers form the first call to the second one, at the end the solution for me was just add a new empty dictionary called 'headers' and then add the custom headers that I want to pass to the next API, the headers Accept,Accept-Encoding',Host, User-Agent,X-Amzn-Trace-Id,X-Forwarded-For,X-Forwarded-Port,X-Forwarded-Proto were added automatically with the correct request context plus my custom headers

```
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    method='POST'
    headers={}
    header['custom-header1']
    header['custom-header2']
    body='some test body'
    url = 'https://dummy.execute-api.dummyregion.amazonaws.com/dummy/test'
    response = requests.request(method, url, data=body, headers=headers)
```